# How to subset two different periods in a text file?

Tags: r, text, subset

I have a text file for two years of data that I want to extract from it two different periods(July to sept for each year)

Read the file:

```
   wg=read.table("C:\\Users\\ERIE.txt", sep ='' , header =TRUE)
   head(wg)
          Year day hour mint valu1 valu2       date
   105169 2008   1    7   30 0.045 0.014 2008-01-01
   105217 2008   2    7   30 0.046 0.015 2008-01-02
   105265 2008   3    7   30 0.043 0.013 2008-01-03
```

Now subset:

```
wg= subset(wg, wg$date >= "2008-07-01" & wg$date <= "2008-09-30" & wg$date >=  "2009-07-01" & wg$date <= "2009-09-30")
 > wg
 [1] Year  day   hour  mint  valu1 valu2 date 
 <0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
 wg= subset(wg, date >= "2008-07-01" & date <= "2008-09-30" & date >=  "2009-07-01" & date <= "2009-09-30")
  > wg
  [1] Year  day   hour  mint  valu1 valu2 date 
   <0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
```

Any idea why it did not work

Comment: I think you need to turn your date column into class `Date`. See `?Date`.

Comment: `> class(wg$date)
[1] "Date"`

Comment: Ni month variable in the data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#one way is to use `filter` from `dplyr` package (and assuming Date is already in Date format)
library(dplyr)
wg %>%
filter(year %in% c(2008,2009) & months(Date) %in% c("July","August","September")
```

`#If you want to stick to subset, replace second & with |:`

`subset(wg, date >= "2008-07-01" & date <= "2008-09-30" | date >=  "2009-07-01" & date <= "2009-09-30")`

Comment: Yep, the second `&` must be the reason

Comment: `yes the second & is  the reason. Another thing please what if I want to exclude the period selected in my example(instead of keeping it!)`

Comment: Just add a `!` in front of the condition: `subset(wg, !(date >= "..." etc.))`. I've added a better example in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

**Edit**: as Metrics pointed out, you had a `&` instead of a `|` in your code. Here is a reproducible example showing how to select or exclude dates within a range using `subset`:

```
> mydat <- data.frame(dat = seq(as.Date("2015-01-01"), as.Date("2015-01-15"), by = "days"), x = "x")
> mydat
          dat x
1  2015-01-01 x
2  2015-01-02 x
3  2015-01-03 x
4  2015-01-04 x
5  2015-01-05 x
6  2015-01-06 x
7  2015-01-07 x
8  2015-01-08 x
9  2015-01-09 x
10 2015-01-10 x
11 2015-01-11 x
12 2015-01-12 x
13 2015-01-13 x
14 2015-01-14 x
15 2015-01-15 x
> subset(mydat, (dat >= "2015-01-05" & dat <= "2015-01-08") | (dat >= "2015-01-11" & dat <= "2015-01-13"))
          dat x
5  2015-01-05 x
6  2015-01-06 x
7  2015-01-07 x
8  2015-01-08 x
11 2015-01-11 x
12 2015-01-12 x
13 2015-01-13 x
> subset(mydat, !((dat >= "2015-01-05" & dat <= "2015-01-08") | (dat >= "2015-01-11" & dat <= "2015-01-13")))
          dat x
1  2015-01-01 x
2  2015-01-02 x
3  2015-01-03 x
4  2015-01-04 x
9  2015-01-09 x
10 2015-01-10 x
14 2015-01-14 x
15 2015-01-15 x
```

Comment: Confused which one deserves the correct answer as both are correct!